# Share only iTunes Match between two devices

Tags: iphone, apple-id, ios, itunes-match

My wife and I have separate Apple IDs, but all of our music is in my iTunes Match "account".  Can I share just that between our phones, keeping everything else separate?  We both have IOS 7 installed.

Answer (score 1):

In Settings -> Store, make sure you’re signed into the account that has all the music/media/etc. (iOS lets you have one Apple ID signed in for iCloud and another for store purchases).

Then, in Settings -> Music, turn iTunes Match on. In iTunes for Mac, go to Store -> Turn Off iTunes Match.

The iTunes Match will then only be on your iTunes devices, but your Macs won’t have any iTunes Match.